# Why airflow is returning error while requesting Rest API?

Tags: python, api, airflow

I have a python code which is requesting a Rest API. The API has more than 5000+ pages so i tried to request it but always i am getting error at 2000th request.

The error is: "df = pd.json_normalize(json_data["items"])
KeyError: 'items'"
How can i solve this problem ?
P.S. In locally, the code is working clearly.

Comment: maybe 2000 is the limit and you're getting the ban hammer

Comment: But recently, I tried it again and it gave me error at 2300 :D. I really dont understand whats happening

Comment: This is not Airflow error. Airflow is just exposing the error as it's workflow orchestrator . The error is generated from whatever API you are querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. Like @elad said, this is not a airflow error. Due to airflow web service and scheduler the system working a little bit slower. So, my token expired while airflow tasks running. I reorganized my code, I generated token in loop with specific conditions such as try-except. Thanks for everything !